# Fogbugz: Is there a way to search for all cases that a specific user made a specific edit

Tags: fogbugz

For example, search for `editedBy:<USER> madeChange:"changed estimate field"` (possibly: `editedOn:Yesterday`).

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to search for specific edit, but try asking at fogbugz.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's not possible to do this.  One very useful one would be: `editedbyme:yesterday`.  It's not possible to combine criteria like this to restrict.  `editedby:me edited:yesterday` gives you everything that's been edited by you (ever) that was edited (by anyone) yesterday.